# Receiving error: {"status":-1,"error":"The operation couldn’t be completed. No space left on device"} using 'cordova-plugin-advanced-http'

Tags: ios, angular, http, ionic-framework, error-handling

I have recently been receiving the following error from 'cordova-plugin-advanced-http'.
{"status":-1,"error":"The operation couldn’t be completed. No space left on device"}

Using this plugin within my project, most of the time, all API calls are successful, however, sometimes, I receive this error message. Not on any particular API call either. I can't for the life of me figure out why nor have I found much online to narrow the problem down.

The project uses:
Ionic 6.19.1
Capacitor 3.5.1
Angular 13.3.8

I have recently updated all three frameworks because this problem was occurring on older versions too but updating them has not resolved the issue.

All devices using my project are iPads (IOS).

Has anyone come across this problem before, know why I am receiving this error, or know how to fix the issue?

Thank you in advance!

***UPDATE***
The device is printing the following error when a call fails with the above error code:

```
finished with error [28] Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=28 "No space left on device" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask
```

Comment: It says "No space left on device". Do you have free disk space on the device?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev Belyaev Yup, plenty. Have even purchased a brand new iPad, downloaded nothing else onto it other than my project, and still receive this error.

Comment: Then the error might be coming from the server. When you say "Not on any particular API call either", does that mean that you get such errors from different hosts or from different API endpoints of the same host? In the latter case I'd suggest to check that host, may be it's running low on disk space.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev Project is calling the same server, 3 different endpoints. Issue has occured when calling all 3 different endpoints. Have discussed this issue with our server provider and they had not come across this error before. I still have truckloads of space available on the server.  I have 200+ iPads making calls to the server all day without fault. I have a suspicion the problem has something to do with IOS 15+. It seems to only happen on iPads running the latest IOS version.

Comment: I would try the following as next steps:
1. Look in the server logs, especially error logs (provided that this error comes with as 4xx or 5xx HTTP status code). 2. Set up a debugging proxy (like Proxyman or Charles) for one of the devices and see what responses the app receives from the server. If the response comes with a valid content from the server but inside the app it gets transformed into this error, the problem is on the app side, otherwise you need to look for something between your device and the server, like a proxy of some sort.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev The calls that fail do not reach the server. I log all calls that hit the server (from the server's end). When a call fails, it's not hitting the server so presumably somethings going wrong from the client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution***

Hey team - came across a similar post, where the answer solved my problem. Check it out if you're stuck on in similar situation:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/downloading-appflow-update-on-ios-gets-to-16-then-errors-with-the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-no-space-left-on-device/222534

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: More of a comment rather than an answer